# Sorting times into bins

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data.table of about 120,000 rows. Each row represents a photo taken by a camera. I am trying to sort these photos into bins by camera and date. For now I have a script that works but I just feel like there has to be a faster way. The script takes about 20 minutes to run through all the photos. I am not completely new to R but I am totally self taught so I am sure there is a lot that could be improved in my coding. I'm open to any advice and help. Here is my code:

```
# Create a list of the different camera stations to run through and bin photos
station_list <- unique(stations_tbl$year_unit_station)

for (station in station_list){
  
  station_visits <- filter(visits_tbl, year_unit_station == station) # Filter visit info to just one station
  start_dttm <- station_visits[1, install_dttm] # Use install time as the left bracket for the first bin
  for (i in 1:nrow(station_visits)){
    
    end_dttm <- station_visits[i, service_end_dttm] # Set the service end as the right bracket for the bin
    bin_title <- paste(station_visits[i, year_unit_station], i, sep = "_") # Give the bin a name not based on the visit number (was told it was not consistent)
    visits_tbl <- within(visits_tbl, bin_name[year_unit_station == station &
                                                service_end_dttm == end_dttm] <- bin_title) # Assign the bin_name to the visit, bin refers to the photos take prior to the visit
    photo_tbl <- within(photo_tbl, 
                               bin_name[year_unit_station == station &
                                          Creation_Datetime > start_dttm &
                                          Creation_Datetime < end_dttm] <- bin_title) # Assign bins to photos
    
    start_dttm <- end_dttm # Set up the left bracket time for the next bin
    
  }
}
```

I'm not sure the best way to share a subset of my data.tables, but here is a header from each (these were after running the above script):

```
dput(head(bin_tbl))
structure(list(year_unit_station = c("2011_002_02", "2011_002_02", 
"2011_002_02", "2011_002_02", "2011_002_02", "2011_002_02"), 
    bin_ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), bin_start = structure(c(1312534800, 
    1312707600, 1312880400, 1313053200, 1313226000, 1313398800
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), bin_end = structure(c(1312707600, 
    1312880400, 1313053200, 1313226000, 1313398800, 1313571600
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000265eafb1ef0>)

dput(head(photo_tbl))
structure(list(year_unit_station = c("2015_004_02", "2015_004_02", 
"2015_004_02", "2015_004_02", "2015_004_02", "2015_004_02"), 
    photo_id = c("2015_SNFPA004_02_0332.JPG", "2015_SNFPA004_02_0331.JPG", 
    "2015_SNFPA004_02_0330.JPG", "2015_SNFPA004_02_0329.JPG", 
    "2015_SNFPA004_02_0328.JPG", "2015_SNFPA004_02_0327.JPG"), 
    Creation_Datetime = structure(c(1443505320, 1443505320, 1443505260, 
    1443505200, 1443504840, 1443504840), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000265eafb1ef0>)
```

****EDIT TO ADD MORE INDEPTH DESCRIPTION****

Each camera was a wildlife camera that was set up in the woods to take a photo every time an animal went past it. The cameras were visited and the photos downloaded approximately once a week. I want to sort the photos into bins for each time each camera was visited. i.e. if a camera was visited at 3pm on 6/12/2018 then again at 8am on 6/19/2018, which (if any) photos were taken by that camera between those times? Additionally I am hoping to set up a script where I can adjust these time bins as needed for our research. i.e. if a camera was set up at 3pm on 6/1/2018 and the last time it was visited was 2pm on 6/22/2018, for every 15 minute time slot between these times, which (if any) photos were taken? The station_tbl contains all the cameras that were set up throughout the multiyear study. The visits_tbl contains information about each time a camera was visited and when the camera was initially installed (the last time each camera is visited is considered the time it was taken down). The photo_tbl includes information about every photo taken by every camera.

Comment: You can use `dput` to provide your data in format that we can use. You can provide just the first 6 rows using `dput(head(stations_tbl))`. Just edit your original post and include the `dput` output for each data table, rather than the `head` output.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question to include that ```dput(head())``` output.

Comment: The role of stations/visits/photos in sorting by "camera and date" is not clear. For example, `photo_tbl` has `CreationDatetime` and `Unit_Station` variables. It might be simpler to merge the fields you need from `visits_tbl` and `stations_tbl` into `photo_tbl` and then split it into a list of data frames.

Comment: @dcarlson I edited the question to include more detail about the goal. I certainly could merge the tables into one and then split them into data frames but I am not sure on a good way to do that without a lot columns and blank values for each camera.

Comment: You would only include the relevant columns, not everything in each table. You need to be able to link each photo to a location and a date/time. If you have a table of visits including the location, date/time start and date/time finish, you can pull out the photos. That would just involve using `subset` to pull out what you want. If you want to organize by "visit" you will have to create a list of visits with a unique ID and their beginning and ending date/times. You have columns named things like Visit_Number and VisitNo, but it is not clear what they are.

Comment: @dcarlson Ok I changed my tables around. I've updated the question to show the new minimalistic tables. I am not sure how I could use subset to run through all of this and assign a bin to each photo. I think I know how to use it to go through each bin one at a time and have it list the photos for that bin but I'm stuck on assigning a value to the photo table that gives me what bin the photo belongs in. Would the best option be a `for` loop with `subset` and `rbind` to update one large master table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a place to start. Your data is not sufficient to test it because `bin_tbl` contains only data from 2011 and `photo_tbl` only data from 2015. You have to pass through all the photos for each bin, but you only have to do that once:

```
bins <- lapply(seq(nrow(bin_tbl)), function(i) which(bin_tbl$year_unit_station[i] == photo_tbl$year_unit_station
& bin_tbl$bin_start[i]<= photo_tbl$Creation_Datetime
& bin_tbl$bin_end[i] >= photo_tbl$Creation_Datetime))
names(bins) <- bin_tbl$bin_ID
```

This will return a list called `bins` that indicate which rows in `photo_tbl` belong to each bin. For example `photo_tbl[bins[[1]], ]` should list the rows in bin 1. You can also use that to create a new variable in photo_tbl for the bin.

Comment: Thanks, this worked after a little editting and I think it makes sense to me. This is how I adjusted it: `bins <- lapply(seq(nrow(photo_tbl)), function(i) which(photo_tbl$year_unit_station[i] == bin_tbl$year_unit_station & photo_tbl$Creation_Datetime[i] >= bin_tbl$bin_start & photo_tbl$Creation_Datetime[i] <= bin_tbl$bin_end))` This gave me a list with the rownumber of the bin for each photo in order of the photo_tbl. I just used turned this into a data.table and did a couple joins to get it the information where I needed. It's a little messy but way better than before.